# Why geometry node setup 2 doesn't work like setup 1?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Why geometry node **setup 2** doesn't result in radial aligned cones like **setup 1**?
I am new to Blender geometry nodes and use Blender version 3.4.1 .

**Setup 1:**
[image]

**Result of setup 1 (radial aligned cones on a spere):**
[image]

**Setup 2:**
[image: Setup 2]

**Result of setup 2 (vertical aligned cones on a spere):**
[image: vertical aligned cones on a spere]

Comment: Points do not have normals. But to use the normals of the previously existing points anyway, you would have to capture these normals with `Capture Attribute` before the `Mesh to Points` node. Then this information remains in the point domain.

Comment: ty, I got ur idea and it really worked. I post the new setup with the capture node to my original post ..-

Answer (score 1):

realizing quellenform's hint resulted in fixing setup 2:

[image]